# Code-first like approach in Dropwizard Migrations Liquibase

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase, dropwizard

Currently I'm working on a small web service using Dropwizard, connecting to a Postgresql DB using hibernate(build in package in Dropwizard) and with a bit of Migrations(also from Dropwizard).

Coming from a .NET environment, I'm used to a code - first/centric approach.
Currently I'm looking into generating the migrations.xml from the current state of my entity class based on the JPA annotations on them.
I feel this is a case somebody might have already resolved.

Is there a way to automatically update the migrations.xml based on the classes I'm writting?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. See the liquibase-hibernate plugin at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki.

Make sure you look at the generated migrations.xml changes before applying them because, like any diff-based process, the schema transformation may not be what you intended and that matters with data. For example, if you rename a class it will generate a drop + create process rather than a rename operation. The result is a valid schema, but you lose data.

Comment: My issue with that is Dropwizard does not use a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file